# How can I implement a multi-picture upload feature similar to WhatsApp's in my mobile website?

Tags: camera, whatsapp

I have been exploring different solutions for an issue I'm facing with my mobile website. The main purpose of the website is to allow users to take pictures of products and save them on the server.

With the solutions I have tried so far, I have encountered two challenges. First, I either have to take multiple photos beforehand and then use the camera roll to select and upload them all at once. Alternatively, I have to open the camera multiple times to take individual pictures, which is not efficient.

My goal is to implement a system similar to WhatsApp's when sending pictures in a chat. In the following picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WBy1.png), you can see a plus button that appears when taking a picture within a chat. This button allows users to take multiple pictures and send them together. I want to achieve the same functionality on my website.

Specifically, I would like to have a button on my website that, when clicked, opens the camera. Then, I should be able to press the camera button multiple times (let's say five times) to capture five pictures. Finally, these five pictures should be uploaded to my server.

I hope I have provided enough explanation. Please note that English is not my primary language, so I apologize for any language-related issues. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I've tried several standarized solutions without luck
my code is PHP, Javascript and HTML